# How many non-negative integer solutions are there for the equation $x+y+z = 11$ when $x \geq 1$, $y \geq 2$, and $z \geq 3$?

Tags: combinatorics

So, if $x+y+z=11$, and $x \ge 1, y \ge 2$, and $z \ge 3$, how many non negative integer solutions can it have?

So far, I did the math this way:

$C(10 + (3-1),10) = C(12,10)$ for $x$ being at least greater than or equal to one.

$C(9 + (3-1),9) = C(11,9)$ for $y$ being at least greater than or equal to two.

$C(8 + (3-1),8) = C(10,8)$ for $z$ being at least greater than or equal to three.

Finally, I multiply the three solutions together to get ${12 \choose 10}{11 \choose 9}{10 \choose 8}$. Is this correct?

Comment: It's quite unnecessary to emphasize that the solutions should be non-negative while having the constraint that $x\geq 1$, $y\geq 2$ and $z\geq 3$. Also, your answer is incorrect because you're not taking into account that $x+y+z=11$

Comment: That came straight off the question. That wasn't my doing, @vrugtehagel.

Comment: So, instead of multiplying, I should Add the solutions together?

Comment: This is an instance of the [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: ... although I have never read the Wikipedia entry on that before, and frankly, the statement of the two theorems on there looks pretty horrendous...

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=x$, $b=y-1$ and $c=z-2$, so that $a,b,c>0$. We know that $x+y+z=11$, and so $a+b+c=11-1-2$, so $$a+b+c=8$$ Now how do we find the number of solutions to $a,b,c$? We can look at it this way:

```
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
```

Now we may place two plus signs at the place of a dot, for example

```
1+1.1.1+1.1.1.1
```

Which would translate to the solution $1+3+4=8$, so $(a,b,c)=(1,3,4)$. We can now make all solutions this way, without counting solutions multiple times. How many ways can we pick two out of the $7$ dots? Exactly ${7\choose 2}=21$ ways.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt, you counted the number of solutions in which $x \geq 1$ or $y \geq 2$ or $z \geq 3$ without taking into account that these conditions could hold simultaneously.  However, the question asks you to find the number of solutions in which all three conditions hold simultaneously.

We wish to solve the equation
$$x + y + z = 11 \tag{1}$$
subject to the constraints $x \geq 1$, $y \geq 2$, and $z \geq 3$.  Let 
\begin{align*}
x' & = x - 1\\  
y' & = y - 2\\
z' & = z - 3
\end{align*}
Then $x'$, $y'$, and $z'$ are non-negative integers.  Substituting $x' + 1$ for $x$, $y' + 2$ for $y$, and $z' + 3$ for $z$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x' + 1 + y' + 2 + z' + 3 & = 11\\
x' + y' + z' & = 5 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the non-negative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to placing two addition signs in a row of five ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 1 + 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x' = 3$, $y' = 1$, $z' = 1$, while
$$+ 1 1 + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x' = 0$, $y' = 2$, $z' = 3$.  Thus, the number of solutions of equation 2 is the number of ways two addition signs can be inserted into a row of five ones, which is 
$$\binom{5 + 2}{2} = \binom{7}{2}$$
since we must select which two of the seven symbols (five ones and two addition signs) will be addition signs.

Answer (score 0):

Number of solutions is the coefficient of $a^{11}$ in 
$$
(a^1+a^2+\cdots)(a^2+a^3+\cdots)(a^3+a^4+\cdots)={a^6\over(1-a)^3}
$$
or equivalently in 
$$
a^6\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{2+k}{k}a^k
$$
which equals
$\binom{7}{5}=\binom{7}{2}=21$.

The reason behind this is $a^x\cdot a^y\cdot a^z=a^{x+y+z}=a^{11}$. $a^x\in\{a^1,a^2,\cdots\},a^y\in\{a^2,a^3,\cdots\},a^z\in\{a^3,a^4,\cdots\}$. So each solution contributes $1$ to the coefficient of $a^{11}$ in the product
$$(a^1+a^2+\cdots)(a^2+a^3+\cdots)(a^3+a^4+\cdots)
$$

Comment: I think the OP wishes to understand the problem rather than someone just throwing the answer onto his lap

Comment: @vrugtehagel edited